# Core Data Problems with saving changes in NSManagedObjectContext

Tags: core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I am experiencing problems with how I handle my Core Data `NSManagedObjectContext`.

I can create `NSManagedObject` in my `NSManagedObjectContext`, but I failed to save the value.

Here's what I got:

```
_lesson.title = _titleField.text;

int priority = [_priorityField.text intValue];
int difficulty = [_difficultyField.text intValue];
int time = [_timeField.text intValue];
int sortIndex = 0;
if ( time == 0 )
{
    sortIndex = 101;
}
else
{
    sortIndex = priority * ( difficulty / time );
}
_lesson.priority = [NSNumber numberWithInt:priority];
_lesson.difficulty = [NSNumber numberWithInt:difficulty];
_lesson.time = [NSNumber numberWithInt:time];
_lesson.sortIndex = [NSNumber numberWithInt:sortIndex];
NSError* error = nil;
[[(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext] save:&error];
```

Everything before the saving is working perfectly, I used `NSLog` to verify if each value is really saved in `_lesson`.

And `_lesson` is sent from here:

```
if ( [[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"addLesson"] )
{
    LessonViewController* destination = [[LessonViewController alloc]init];
    Lesson* lesson = (Lesson*)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Lesson" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
    destination.lesson = lesson;
}
else if ( [[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"editLesson"] )
{
    LessonViewController* destination = [[LessonViewController alloc]init];
    NSIndexPath* index = [_tableView indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell*)sender];
    [_managedObjectContext deleteObject:[_lessonArray objectAtIndex:index.row]];
    Lesson* lesson = (Lesson*)[_lessonArray objectAtIndex:index.row];
    destination.lesson = lesson;
}
```

After debugging for two hours, I cannot find my error. Please help!

I will include my full code below:

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/eu62ie9svbbqdmm/u1hYUICfjy

That is my full source code. (I copied and pasted and created a mess. So, Dropbox!)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line looks suspicious:

```
[_managedObjectContext deleteObject:[_lessonArray objectAtIndex:index.row]];
```

You delete the *Lesson* object before passing it to the `LessonViewController`, so that saving the context will delete that object from the store, and not save a (modified) object, as you probably intended.

It seems to me that you should just delete that line in your code.

---

*ADDED:* There is an error in your `prepareForSegue` method: You create a *new* view controller with

```
LessonViewController* destination = [[LessonViewController alloc]init];
```

Instead, you must use the destination view controller of the seque:

```
LessonViewController *destination = [segue destinationViewController];
```

Comment: It's a line of code from a previous method of handling editing. Before even deleting it, I really want to take a minute and say to myself "Wow, you're stupid." I will remove that line and try again. Thanks for reading that long code.

Comment: After realizing I am stupid. Another problem strikes me. The data is not being edited, so that line would not really execute for now as I'm not really trying to edit anything just yet. But you're right, that line should be deleted.

Comment: @ShaneHsu: Do you reload the table view in the ProjectViewController, when a lesson has been added? Otherwise you would not see the new object in the table view.

Comment: The saving part. I can add a Lesson to the context with `insertNewObjectForEntityForName`, and pass that Lesson to my editing view. But when I save my edit, and wants to come back to the Table View, all the data is gone. They remain blank. The record is there, but it's empty. I will put my source code on Dropbox.

Comment: @ShaneHsu: OK, I can have a look at it. What about my "reload" question?

Comment: I don't think I have too, it does that automatically when I do a modal segue back to the Project View. That's why the new data appears, but with blank value. Here's the link to the ZIP archive: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/eu62ie9svbbqdmm/u1hYUICfjy

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21529/discussion-between-shane-hsu-and-martin-r)